# Pandas remove null values when to_json

Tags: python, json, pandas

i have  actually a pandas dataframe and i want to save it to json format.
From the pandas docs it says:

> Note NaN‘s, NaT‘s and None will be converted to null and datetime
>   objects will be converted based on the date_format and date_unit
>   parameters

Then using the orient option `records`  i have something like this

```
[{"A":1,"B":4,"C":7},{"A":null,"B":5,"C":null},{"A":3,"B":null,"C":null}]
```

Is it possible to have this instead:

```
[{"A":1,"B":4,"C":7},{"B":5},{"A":3}]'
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you just `dropna` the nulls before writing the JSON?

Comment: @katrielalex I think it's more complicated than that, dropna will remove rows or columns, the OP is asking if it's possible to remove single elements so the final json doesn't even have an entry for that element

Comment: @EdChum yes you are right

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to either generate the dirct for each row where you can drop the `NaN` values, or to parse the json dict and strip the entries out, I don't think dfs will allow a form where the dimensions are different for each row. Thinking about it you could create a dict for each row that doesn't contain the NaN values and then call `to_json` on that column, let me try this

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: [x.dropna()], axis=1).to_json()` gets close to what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following gets close to what you want, essentially we create a list of the non-NaN values and then call `to_json` on this:

```
In [136]:
df.apply(lambda x: [x.dropna()], axis=1).to_json()

Out[136]:
'{"0":[{"a":1.0,"b":4.0,"c":7.0}],"1":[{"b":5.0}],"2":[{"a":3.0}]}'
```

creating a list is necessary here otherwise it will try to align the result with your original df shape and this will reintroduce the `NaN` values which is what you want to avoid:

```
In [138]:
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna()), axis=1).to_json()

Out[138]:
'{"a":{"0":1.0,"1":null,"2":3.0},"b":{"0":4.0,"1":5.0,"2":null},"c":{"0":7.0,"1":null,"2":null}}'
```

also calling `list` on the result of `dropna` will broadcast the result with the shape, like filling:

```
In [137]:
df.apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna()), axis=1).to_json()

Out[137]:
'{"a":{"0":1.0,"1":5.0,"2":3.0},"b":{"0":4.0,"1":5.0,"2":3.0},"c":{"0":7.0,"1":5.0,"2":3.0}}'
```

Comment: thank you it works but for orient options columns labels doesn't show up because it's assuming your input are series type

Comment: Sorry are you saying `df.apply(lambda x: [x.dropna()], axis=1).to_json(orient='columns')` doesn't work or it doesn't give you the desired output?

Comment: it works but it doesn't give the desired output for the case when i set orient options to "records"

Comment: yeah this is tricky one, can't help with that. Like I said the other thing would be to post-process the resultant dict and remove the entries in the nested dicts that have a null entry is one possiblity

Answer (score 17):

The solution above doesn't actually produce results in the 'records' format.  This solution also uses the json package, but produces exactly the result asked for in the original question.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

json.dumps([row.dropna().to_dict() for index,row in df.iterrows()])
```

Additionally, if you want to include the index (and you are on Python 3.5+) you can do:

```
json.dumps([{'index':index, **row.dropna().to_dict()} for index,row in df.iterrows()])
```

Comment: very nice!  this helped me turn a highly sparse pivot table into a No-SQL ready insert in just one line :)

Comment: This is genius. Pandas should have this as an option. Thank you.

Comment: Note to my future self coming back again to this answer : check the non-`iterrows` answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The most-upvoted answer uses `iterrows()`, which is not considered as best practice because of poor performances on large dataframes.  The following solution only has similar performances on my use case, but maybe it will be better for other datasets ?

So one can use instead

```
df.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict(), axis=1)
```

to convert the dataframe into a series of dictionaries without null values.  Then one can transform the series into a JSON list :

```
import json
json.dumps(list(df.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict(), axis=1)))
```

Comment: Note that using json.dumps on a DataFrame.to_dict() result, will fail in situations where e.g. the DataFrame has values json.dumps doesn't know how to handle (e.g. various special int types, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and my solution is use **json** module instead of **pd.DataFrame.to_json()**

My solution is

1. drop the NaN value when converting DataFrame to dict, and then
2. convert dict to json using json.dumps()

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import compat

def to_dict_dropna(df):
   return {int(k): v.dropna().astype(int).to_dict() for k, v in compat.iteritems(df)}

json.dumps(to_dict_dropna(df))
```