# json dumps TypeError: keys must be a string with dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pandas

I want to solve the problem similar to [Pandas remove null values when to_json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912746/pandas-remove-null-values-when-to-json).

My solution is

1. drop the `NaN` value when converting DataFrame to dict, and then
2. convert dict to json using `json.dumps()`

Here is my code and the error:

```
In [9]:df

Out[9]:
    101 102
  a 123 NaN
  b 234 234
  c NaN 456

In [10]:def to_dict_dropna(data):
          return dict((k, v.dropna().to_dict()) for k, v in compat.iteritems(data))

In [47]:k2 = to_dict_dropna(df)
In [48]:k2
Out[48]:{101: {'a': 123.0, 'b': 234.0}, 102: {'b': 234.0, 'c': 456.0}}
In [49]:json.dumps(k2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-f0159cf5a097> in <module>()
----> 1 json.dumps(k2)

C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.pyc in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, encoding, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    241         cls is None and indent is None and separators is None and
    242         encoding == 'utf-8' and default is None and not sort_keys and not kw):
--> 243         return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
    244     if cls is None:
    245         cls = JSONEncoder

C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.pyc in encode(self, o)
    205         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    206         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 207         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    208         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    209             chunks = list(chunks)

C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.pyc in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    268                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    269                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 270         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    271 
    272 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

TypeError: keys must be a string
```

But it works if I directly initialize a dict:

```
In [65]:k = {101: {'a': 123.0, 'b': 234.0}, 102: { 'b': 234.0, 'c': 456.0}}
In [66]:k == k2
Out[66]:True
In [63]:json.dumps(k)
Out[63]:'{"101": {"a": 123.0, "b": 234.0}, "102": {"c": 456.0, "b": 234.0}}'
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Interesting, I'd have expected both dictionaries to fail. The work-around would be for you to use `dict((str(k), v.dropna().to_dict()) for k, v in compat.iteritems(data))` (or `{str(k): v.dropna().to_dict()) for k, v in compat.iteritems(data)}` using dict comprehension notation).

Comment: The JSON C source code explicitly tests for `int`, `long`, `float` and `bool` keys, converting all those to strings. This means you have keys that are not really integers but only *mimic* integers (their representation is the same, they test equal, but `isinstance(int, key)` fails).

Answer (score 4):

Your 'integers' in your Pandas dataframe are not really integers. They are `float64` objects, see the [Pandas *Gotchas* documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions).

You'll have to convert them back to `int()` objects, or convert them straight to strings:

```
def to_dict_dropna(data):
     return {int(k): v.dropna().astype(int).to_dict() for k, v in compat.iteritems(data)}
```

does the former.

Comment: Thank you, Martijin. This answers my question.